# Python2.6 xmpp Jabber Error

Tags: python, xmpp

I am using xmpp with python and I want create a simple client to communicate with a gmail
id.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import xmpp

login = 'Your.Login' # @gmail.com 
pwd   = 'YourPassword'

cnx = xmpp.Client('gmail.com')
cnx.connect( server=('talk.google.com',5223) )
cnx.auth(login,pwd, 'botty')

cnx.send( xmpp.Message( "YourFriend@gmail.com" ,"Hello World form Python" ) )
```

When I run the last line I get an exception

> IOError: Disconnected from server.

Also when I run the other statements I get debug messages in the console.

What could be the issue and how can I resolve it ?

Comment: What do the debug statements say right before you got disconnected?  Are you seeing a not-authorized error?

  <failure xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">
    <not-authorized/>
  </failure>

Answer (score 6):

[Here](https://svn.tchoy.net/svn/jTalk/trunk/pyTalk/ConnectorThread.py) is how it did on [my PyTalk client](http://pytalk.trunat.fr/).

**Don't forget the @gmail.com in the userID.**

I think you should try to connect talk.google.com on the 5222 port.

Also try to specify a ressource for the auth.

```
import xmpp
import sys

userID   = 'Your.Login@gmail.com' 
password = 'YourPassword'
ressource = 'Script'

jid  = xmpp.protocol.JID(userID)
jabber     = xmpp.Client(jid.getDomain(), debug=[])

connection = jabber.connect(('talk.google.com',5222))
if not connection:
    sys.stderr.write('Could not connect\n')
else:
    sys.stderr.write('Connected with %s\n' % connection)

auth = jabber.auth(jid.getNode(), password, ressource)
if not auth:
    sys.stderr.write("Could not authenticate\n")
else:
    sys.stderr.write('Authenticate using %s\n' % auth)

jabber.sendInitPresence(requestRoster=1)
jabber.send(xmpp.Message( "YourFriend@gmail.com" ,"Hello World form Python" ))
```

By the way, it looks very close from Philip Answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this code snippet. I didn't handle the error conditions for simplicity's sake.

```
import xmpp

login = 'Your.Login' # @gmail.com 
pwd   = 'YourPassword'

jid = xmpp.protocol.JID(login)
cl  = xmpp.Client(jid.getDomain(), debug=[])
if cl.connect(('talk.google.com',5223)):
    print "Connected"
else:
    print "Connectioned failed"

if cl.auth(jid.getNode(), pwd):
    cl.sendInitPresence()
    cl.send(xmpp.Message( "YourFriend@gmail.com" ,"Hello World form Python" ))
else:
    print "Authentication failed"
```

To switch off the debugging messages, pass **debug=[]** for the 2nd parameter on the Client class's constructor:

```
cl  = xmpp.Client(jid.getDomain(), debug=[])
```

Comment: Tried that Philip but I get authentication failed.  Is there any setting which needs to be changed before trying this ?

Comment: Strange, I just tried it again with the code snippet above, used with a valid gmail username (xxxxx@gmail.com) and password and it sent a message as expected.  This (sub-set) of code runs as a bot on Linux and Windows machines everyday.  Python 2.6 and xmpppy-0.5.0rc1 used. Perhaps make sure the login contains the @gmail.com suffix?

Comment: And also double-check your password. :)

Answer (score 1):

i think you must write this. i test it in python 2.7 with xmpppy 0.5.0rc1  and work IT very nice :P :)  :

```
import xmpp

login = 'your mail@gmail.com' # @gmail.com 
pwd   = 'your pass'
text='Hello worlD!'
tojid='your friend @gmail.com'



jid = xmpp.protocol.JID(login)
cl  = xmpp.Client(jid.getDomain(), debug=[])
if cl.connect(('talk.google.com',5223)):
    print "Connected"

else:
    print "Connectioned failed"

if cl.auth(jid.getNode(), pwd):
    cl.sendInitPresence()
    cl.send(xmpp.protocol.Message(tojid,text))
else:
    print "Authentication failed"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call `sendInitPresence` before sending the first message:

```
...
cnx.auth(login,pwd, 'botty')
cnx.sendInitPresence()
cnx.send( xmpp.Message( "YourFriend@gmail.com" ,"Hello World form Python" ) )
```

Comment: Tried that but I still got the IOError: Disconnected from server error

Comment: Sending presence first is not required.  I just tested against gtalk to make sure they don't have a special rule.